# Is it possible to consistently factor powers of $3$ throughout $\Bbb Z_2$?

Tags: metric-spaces, factoring, p-adic-number-theory

I'm pretty sure I was told it's impossible to identify multiples of $3$, or powers of $3$ in the p-adic ring $\Bbb Z_2$, and this claim makes total sense to me.

Let $f(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$

Is it fair and consistent to define the odd factors of the image of $f$, as the numbers $x$ satisfying $2,3\nmid x$?

If so, let this set be $X$.

Is there any element of $\Bbb Z_2$ which is not in $2^m3^nX:m\in\Bbb N,n\in\Bbb Z$?

I wanted to understand better whether, how and why this approach breaks down.

Comment: $f(5/3)=6$. It's not entirely clear what are "the odd factors" of $6$ as a $2$-adic number, but in any interpretation I can think of, $3$ divides at least one of them.

Comment: Thanks @TorstenSchoeneberg I make myself look really dumb sometimes!  It works for $\Bbb Z$ and kind of in $\Bbb Q$ if we use $3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)}$ but we can't take $3^{\nu_3(x)}$ in $\Bbb Z_2^\times$ as a prerequisite to make $f$ well-defined.  So I guess it works only on the embedding of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb Q_2$.

Comment: Every element of $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is divisible by all the odd primes. That is one of the reasons for going into the 2-adics, I think. So it may be *consistent* but utterly useless. In other words, the exponent $n$ is not well defined. Because $3$ is a 2-adic unit, it is quite like trying to figure out the highest power of $1$ that divides an integer.

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen the analogy is really useful, so what I'm asking for would require something akin to extending real numbers into the complex.